# CSS :after not working properly in FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked before but the suggested [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220445/1584140) is not working for me in firefox properly, though the same works perfect in Chrome and IE. The "+" and "-" signs seems to drop below the heading, which should ideally be in middle of the header's top. Below is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7tg188u5/1/

```css
#accordion [aria-selected="false"] .panel-title a:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2b";
    float: right;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#accordion  [aria-selected="true"] .panel-title a:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2212";
    float: right;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm in Firefox and see the plus/minus displayed on the right, what is the issue exactly, that they aren't floating within the bar?

Comment: @Brian, Yes those should be in the middle from top on right.

Comment: This seems like correct behavior to me, based on what a float:right normally does to layout. Using `:before` would probably work better: http://jsfiddle.net/7tg188u5/3/.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. I've done this before, and :before worked for me but I missed this time. Anyways Thanks for this. Can you add this as answer so that I can mark it as the accepted?

Answer (score 2):

```css
#accordion .panel-heading .panel-title {
    position: relative;   /* <<< New rule */
}
#accordion [aria-selected="false"] .panel-title a:after{
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2b";
    float: right;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;   /* <<< New rule */
    right: 0; top: 0;     /* <<< New rule */
    display:inline-block;
}
#accordion  [aria-selected="true"] .panel-title a:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2212";
    float: right;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: absolute; /* <<< New rule */
    right: 0; top: 0;   /* <<< New rule */
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Note the comments indicating the adjusted lines above, this is using the "workaround" you linked, properly. You'll want to adjust the right/line-height most likely, as this really puts them tight into the corner, but this should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.accordion-toggle {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
#accordion [aria-selected="false"] .panel-title a:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2b";
    right:10px;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}
#accordion  [aria-selected="true"] .panel-title a:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2212";
    right:10px;
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}
.padding0
{
    padding:0px;
}
```

Here's the updated [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tg188u5/2/)