# Cross browser CSS checkbox issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues getting my CSS checkbox to show up on Firefox. I'm using an `:after:` element to style the new checkbox, and it works fine on webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) but isn't visible on Firefox. I've got it so that the native checkbox is visible if the styled one isn't so it's not terrible, but I'd like to have a consistent experience.

It seems as though the `:after` element is just not being rendered in FF when I inspect the code.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="text-center checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="on">
  </label>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.checkbox {
  label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
  &:hover {
    input[type=checkbox] {
      &:after {
        cursor: pointer;
        border-color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    &:after {
      background: white;
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.5em;
      height: 1.5em;
      position: relative;
      top: -4px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 2px solid gray;
      transition: border 0.3s ease;
    }
    &:checked {
      &:after {
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNDkgNDEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGcgaWQ9IlBhZ2UtMSIgc3Ryb2tlPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjEiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCI+PHBvbHlsaW5lIGlkPSJQYXRoIiBzdHJva2U9IiM0MjkxREIiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMTEiIHBvaW50cz0iMy43NTY1MzE0OCAxOC45ODA0MDUyIDIyLjc1Mzc0MjQgMzMuMDg5OTk4NiA0NC41ODgzMTcxIDMuNDk1NDY5MjIiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center left 2px;
        background-size: 75%;
        border-color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have it set up on a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nachiketkumar/pen/vmxWZN). In my CSS file, I've noted where I forked this code from and modified; given the markup we're using I had to make some tweaks to the elements being styled. The inspiration code works cross browser which is further mystifying me!

Answer (score 2):

try this below code for checkbox

```
<style type="text/css">
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 3em;
      background: #efefef;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: contain;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        outline: 0;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 2px solid #dedede;
        transition: border 0.3s ease;


    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:hover{ 
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 2px solid #4291DB;
            transition: border 0.3s ease;

    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
            background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNDkgNDEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGcgaWQ9IlBhZ2UtMSIgc3Ryb2tlPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjEiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCI+PHBvbHlsaW5lIGlkPSJQYXRoIiBzdHJva2U9IiM0MjkxREIiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMTEiIHBvaW50cz0iMy43NTY1MzE0OCAxOC45ODA0MDUyIDIyLjc1Mzc0MjQgMzMuMDg5OTk4NiA0NC41ODgzMTcxIDMuNDk1NDY5MjIiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center left 2px;
            background-size: 75%;

            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 2px solid #4291DB;
            transition: border 0.3s ease;


    }
  </style>
    <div class="text-center">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="on">
      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:before` and `:after` only work on elements with content. `<input>` cannot contain content so it won't work.

More info on this: [doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the label tag as a custom style tag.  I personally tend to put my label after my input.  Not wrap the input.  This way you can do:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {//Basic styles}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {//Checked styles}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christien and Andrew, this helps. I think I'm stuck with using the native checkbox as a fallback since I can't change the markup at this point.

Comment: Ahh, apologies.  I did not know the markup was not able to change.

Comment: Seems somewhat similar to this question, Check it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220360/firefox-not-displaying-properly-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        $(this).closest("label").addClass("checked");
        $(this).closest("label").removeClass("unchecked");
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        $(this).closest("label").addClass("unchecked");
  $(this).closest("label").removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

```css
label input {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
}
label.unchecked {
    background: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
}
label.checked {
    background: green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center checkbox">
  <label class="unchecked">
    <input type="checkbox" value="on">
  </label>
</div>
```